# Select dropdown not active on Android browser (Chrome)

Tags: android, google-chrome, dropdown, typo3-8.x, powermail

I have a problem where a drop-down select box does not drop-down (it's essentially inactive) when viewed on an Android mobile device (chrome browser). It works fine on desktop browsers (chrome, firefox, IE). I use typo3 8.7.27 / powermail extension 7.4.0.

I have checked all CSS code, but nothing works. Any clues?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="powermail_field">

<select class="powermail_select" id="powermail_field_interessensgebiet" name="tx_powermail_pi1[field][interessensgebiet]">

<option value="">(Bitte waehlen)</option>
<option value="Personalentwicklung">Personalentwicklung</option>
<option value="Teamentwicklung">Teamentwicklung</option>
<option value="Organisationsentwicklung">Organisationsentwicklung</option>
<option value="Coaching">Coaching</option>
<option value="Mediation">Mediation</option>
<option value="Workshop">Workshop</option>

</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copied the above HTML code into a blank HTML page.

Test result is attached as it shows drop-down is active.

Mobile - Redmi Note 3.

Android Version - 6.0.1 MMB29M is attached.

Chrome version - 74.0.3729.157

Please check other things for this error.

[Drop-down is active in Android Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA4vO.png)

Comment: Found the source of the problem. Deactivated the "fastclick JS plugin" and now it works. Any workaround for this plugin in order to use it and fix the dropdown issue?

Comment: Found the solution: the problem was the "FastClick JS Plugin". Had to add class="needsclick" to <select>.